# Can you use the headset camera on the HTC Vive in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

I'm working in unity(2018) and building for the HTC Vive VR headset. I had an idea to use the small camera on the front of the headset to make an AR system, as in run the video from the headsets camera to the headset view to then be able to overlap things from a unity environment. But unfortunately, I can't seem to find any examples of others doing this (other than the Tron blue outline system that the Vive comes with) though perhaps I'm not looking with the right keywords.

If anyone has seen something like this or know if it can be done I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is registered as a standard WebCam, so you should be able to use Unitys [`WebCamTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html).
But the resolution of the cameras is very low.